# How to hard delete a user from SQLite database using loops from Flask's View

Tags: python, flask, django-views

I've been working on a really simple,maybe trivial, flask application that manages users' credentials, like a sysadmin page (change username, password, privileges, email).

Right now I've written the following code in HTML:

```
<div id="signup-box" class="signup-box" style=" background-color:rgb(149, 202, 202); width: 60%;">       
          <table class="table" style="background-color:#ffffff00;">
           <thead >
                <tr>
                  <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:inherit;">Username</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center; vertical-align:inherit;">Role</th>
                  <th style="text-align:center; background-color:rgba(104, 159, 223, 0.384);">Control</th>
                <tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>                    
                  {% for i in range(0,lenUser) %}
                  <tr class="tr">

                      <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:inherit;">{{ users[i] }}</td>
                      <td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:inherit;">{{ roles[i] }}</td>
                      <td style="text-align:center;">
                        <button form="edit_form" type="submit" value="Edit" class="button is-warning is-focused" style="margin-right: 45px;">Edit User</button>                                                           
                        <button form="delete_form" type="submit" value="Delete" class="button is-danger is-focused" style="margin-right: 45px;">Delete User</button>                                                                                       
                        <form id="edit_form" action="{{ url_for('edit_user', id=users.id) }}" method="POST">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="EDIT">                                                            
                        </form>
                        <form id="delete_form"action="{{ url_for('delete_user', id=users.id) }}" method="POST">
                          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">                                                                                        
                        </form>
                      </td>                          
                  </tr>
     {% endfor %}           
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

in Python:

@app.route("/delete_user/")

```
def delete_user():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    con = sqlite3.connect('sqlite:///accounts.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM User WHERE id = "' +  request.args.get('id')+ '"')
    cur.commit()
    con.close()
    return flask.jsonify({'success':"True"})
```

And as a Python helper to fetch my users:

```
def fetch_users():
        with session_scope() as s:                                
                 usrs = s.query(tabledef.User.username).order_by(tabledef.User.username).all()
                 tblUsrs = df.from_records(usrs)                             
        return(tblUsrs)
```

Now, what it does is that it fetches my users as a dataframe and it outputs them row by row in my html table, which is what it was intended to do. But I also want to delete the specific user when I press the button "Delete" in the HTML page, right? Problem is that I can't seem to find a way to select the specific id of the user from the following lines:

```
<form id="delete_form"action="{{ url_for('delete_user', id=users.id) }}" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"> 
</form>
```

How can I fix that? Because it is in a loop and every time the string I get is that of the first line

Comment: can you post a sample of how your `users` data looks like

Comment: Doesn't `action="{{ url_for('delete_user', id=users[i].id) }}"` give you the url with the id as an argument?

Comment: @KarthikeyanK I don't really have a way to show you because it is an SQLite db and I'm inputting values through different forms, so I guess (id),(username,password,email)

Comment: @PGHE unfortunately no, I get my link but without the string that reprisents the id. But at this point I've hit rock bottom and I'll get anything, books, advice, even rejected stackoverflow posts

Comment: Try doing a `print` of your `tblUsrs` to check you're getting all the info you need. It looks like your not selecting your `user.id` in your query. I.e. `usrs = s.query(tabledef.User.username)` will only give you the username, you'll need `usrs = s.query(tabledef.User.username, tabledef.User.id)`